# Rotate multiple 'Text' messages in Qt Quick application

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

My application has a message area that can fit only one `Text` item from the below code: But I wanted a logic to rotate the messages `Text 1`, `Text 2` and `Text 3` every one second. So that all the three messages can be displayed in my message area.

```
 import QtQuick 2.3

    Item {

    id: root
    width: 480
    height: 320

    Rectangle {
        color: "#272822"
        width: 480
        height: 320
    }

    Column {
        spacing: 20

        Text {
            text: 'Text 1'
            visible: (timerCount == 1)
        }

        Text {
           text: 'Text 2'
           visible: (timerCount == 2)
        }

        Text {
            text: 'Text 3'
            visible: (timerCount == 3)
       }
    }
}
```

I am able to achieve this using a timer. To set `visible` property of `Text` items based on the `timerCount`.

```
property int timerCount = 0;
Timer {
    id: onesecondtimer

    interval: 1000
    running: true
    repeat: true
    triggeredOnStart: true
    onTriggered: {
           if(++timerCount > 3)
              timerCount=1;
}
```

It works fine, but am not happy with this approach since it gets more difficult if I want to maintain multiple messages (more than 3).

Am just wandering if `QtQuick` already supports something like this, which am not yet able to find. I tried searching Qt documentation for some time but was not able to find it.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a unique `Text` type, maintain an array of strings, i.e. `property var strings: ["text1", "text2", ....]` and assign the `text` property with values in the arrays using an incremented index which is  assigned with `<index_name> + 1 % strings.length`. That would be independent of number of strings and does not use additional types. Just my two cents wrote on a whim.

Comment: Yep, that's a nice way of doing it for my scenario. Thank you. But, I just wanted to explore if we have some thing like `RotateAnimation` or some property that Qt supports which will make this job even more easier. ? Definitely I would like to try your suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the kind of support you are searching for, sorry. You mean some sort of animation type which iterates over the text strings?

Comment: Yes, some sort of animation type which can automatically iterate over the strings.

Comment: Uhm, AFAICT there's nothing built-in for such a purpose. Nothing I can think of. Let's see if someone comes up with something interesting. :)

Comment: When you have different items, not just Text items, it's useful to use states and change the 'children' property.